# I need to copy multiple user selected rows to a different worksheet. The problem is, the selected rows are different each time the macro runs

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

Say the user selected E3 and E4, is there a way to copy the values of E3 and E4, as well as the next three cells on their right (F3:H4)?

I tried using ActiveCell.Resize but I do not know how to copy selected rows since the selected rows change depending on the user.

This is a sample of my code:

```
ActiveCell.Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("b7:e14")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Selection` instead of `ActiveCell`.

`Selection` contains **all** selected cells while `ActiveCell` is always only one cell within the whole `Selection`.

In the following example `Selection` would be `Range("A2,B5,A7,A10:B10")` but `ActiveCell` would be `Range("A10")`.

[image]

Comment: Tried using Selection.Resize instead of ActiveCell.Resize. It worked :) Thank you very much PEH!